# Any alternative for Winkey on Windows 7 64 bit?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-7-x64

I'd like to setup some quick keys on my windows box to quickly open things like Sublime or Chrome a file explorer rooted at a common directory etc.  On XP I used to use WinKey, but Copernic discontinued support.

(For those unfamiliar to WinKey: It's a simple utility that maps the MS Windows Key + Other keys to commands, for example, Shift+WinKey+T might point to the TextPad exe and open that, etc).

Anyone know of an alternative.... Or how I could write something similar using C# or something?

(Also, I've heard of Launchy, etc and I'm not a fan -- I'm looking for a quick key-chord to run a command or .bat or whatever.)

Answer (score 1):

WinHotkey is nearly identical in every way but it works on newer OS's